# What combat abilities did the High Evolutionary demonstrate?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-3

In *Guardians of the Galaxy 3*, the High Evolutionary is feared and respected by the crew of his vessel. He is an enormously intimidating figure. However we don't often see him in combat, except for a formidable demonstration of power in suppressing Adam Warlock, and later when he generates some kind of energy pulse during a disturbance on the bridge of his vessel.

Using supporting material from the comics if necessary, what could this energy pulse power be? And what, if any, other combat abilities did the High Evolutionary demonstrate in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Comment: Earlier, we also see him pin Adam Warlock on the wall, pushing him into the bending material, possibly the same power as the energy pulse. who knows.

Comment: Thanks @iandotkelly, I have improved my question from your comment :-)

Comment: I can't find the quote, but I thought in the film he said that he had the power to control gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As he explains during the confrontation on Counter-Earth, he wears a suit that allows him to control gravity.

> I aim some small part of my mental capacity back in my own direction, and now, gravity itself serves my whims.

In combat he uses this to throw people around with minimal effort. You can see the suit activate with purple energy whenever he does this:

[image: Movie still showing The High Evolutionary's suit powering up]

Comment: Functionally, he's a powerful telekinetic.

Comment: @AaarghZombies unless you have gravity boots. He doesn't demonstrate any fine control either, like a Sorcerer might use.

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone suggested that he did.

Comment: @AaarghZombies you did, when you said he was functionally the same as a powerful telekinetic, but the other powerful telekinetic have fine control

Comment: Power, as in he can hit hard.